# C#, MS ACCESS - OleDb Command.ExecuteReader() take sometime really long time to execute

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2010, oledb, rdbms

I have a Table in my MS Access DataBase which contain 60K+ rows and
i need to take the 50 newest row every 30 Seconds.

I use this query :

```
"SELECT TOP 50 * FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY ID DESC"
```

The problem is that once in a while (+- 1/50) the query take more than 10 Seconds to execute and normaly the average time is 0.03 second.

I experienced the same behaviour with a 10K rows and with only five rows but with smaller delays.

1) Did someone have ever experienced something similar with MS Access Or with the Command.ExecuteReader() function ? Is that a C# problem or a MS ACCES problem ?

C# - The Delay appear once in a while when i execute my reader

```
RunSQLReaderMyTable(myCommand.ExecuteReader());
```

The problem is not in the RunSQLReaderMyTable function because i have timewatch and i can see that the MyCommand.ExecuteReader() is the problem.

```
//SELECT ROWS FROM MY_TABLE
public static DataTable SelectTopMyTable()
{
    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr))
    {
        string tmpStr = "SELECT TOP 50 * FROM HISTORIQUE ORDER BY ID DESC";

        using (OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(tmpStr, con))
        {
            if (IsConnectedToAccess())
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    return RunSQLReaderMyTable(myCommand.ExecuteReader());
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
                    return null;
                }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erreur de connexion a Access. Veuillez tenter de vous reconnecter.");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you replace `*` with a list of only the fieldnames you actually need? This may help reduce the complexity of your query.

Comment: @Bob Kaufman - No, because i need every Column

Comment: Its normal that an Access DB grows, your issue 1 is maybe related to your issue 2: you should make compact/repair of your DB ona regular basis. That removes all garbage which decrease the size, and increase the perfs

Comment: @ThomasG - The compact/repair was a good idea My DB Goes from 197MB to 20 MB, But my first problem is not resolved, stil have long delay +- 1/50

Comment: Depending on what your application is for I would suggest moving to a slightly more capable RDBMS. Probably MSSQLServer Express (again, depending on your application) That will give it some dedicated resources to run your query

Comment: @LordBaconPants I would like to move to Mysql, Is it right to say that Mysql is as fast as MSSQLServer Express ?

Comment: @MrRubix I'm not familiar enough with either anymore to give you a good answer on that one. SQLExpress has (had?) some hard limits put on it that mySQL may not, like RAM useage. It may pay to check out the latest offering of both and compare as I'm sure they have changed since I last looked

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is a "Question and Answer" site, not a site for extended, meandering discussions. Please limit your questions to a single topic, in this case the occasional delays in executing your query. The additional "database bloat" issue is a duplicate, and the "should I switch databases"  and "is MySQL as fast as MSSQL" tangents are off-topic.

Comment: Is this table (or the database) sometimes used by another user or another process?

Comment: @Andre - good question but no, the database is only used by my main program !

Comment: Hmm. Maybe it *is* your own program. If you need to take the 50 newest records every 30 seconds, I assume there are quite a few inserts going on. Are those processes running asynchronously? --- My best guess is a locking conflict. You'd have to expand your question with details about the whole setup, so we can make more educated guesses...

Comment: Is ID indexed (sorry for asking) ? By the way, using a transaction (even for a select) speeds things a lot.

Comment: @Larry - Yes ID is indexed, I checked.

Comment: @Andre I find out that this function is triggered at each 5 seconds and an other function is triggered just before this one. Can rapid access to DB can be dangerous ?

Comment: Not if the functions run strictly in succession, i.e. the second doesn't start until the first has completely finished. But if they run in parallel, you can get locking conflicts.

Comment: @Andre In my log file i can see that they run in succession !